# Dropdown list from a TextFormField

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a simple `TextFormField` in my app, how can I make that when I press the first letter, there should be dropping down a list with every option that begins with that specific letter? And when I pressed the second letter, only the valid options remain, and so on and so on. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Please add/share code snippet of what you've tried

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [`flutter_typeahead`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_typeahead) package.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try `dropdown_search` https://pub.dev/packages/dropdown_search, this package seems helpful

Answer (score 0):

instead of `textformfield` try to use the `autocomplete` widget